# MS SQL Server with Rails 4

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create an application on Rails 4 that would use existent MS SQL database.
This application could greatly benefit from using Rails 4 and all its new features
But it seems the gem everyone recomend to use - activerecord-sqlserver-adapter  doesn't support rails 4.0.0 -  https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/250
Does anyone could advice is there any other ways to connect to MS SQL Server without using this gem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might need to wait it out. Rails 4 isn't released yet, not even a release candidate is out yet, so many gems not just one will just plain NOT work. I did some searching and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` is the only Microsoft Database driver.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this fork while looking for the same: https://github.com/arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.  Can't say how complete it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/sic-activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) to use MS SQL Server 5 and higher with Rails 4.

```
sudo gem install sic-activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
```

This will work with Rails 4 definitely, i have tried this. thanks.

Another, good news, rails 4 supportive version released for activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

now we can use below gem for MS-SQL with Rails 4

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.0.0'
```

along with Runtime Dependencies

```
activerecord ~> 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an update from the discussion from issue: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/pull/278

IMHO, the best fork so far (that I could test) is https://github.com/annaswims/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/tree/rails-4 mainly for beeing transparent about the progress on the test base.

Comment: Thanks!  My fork is now merged into https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.  It's one complicated Arel fix away from being released.

Answer (score 0):

[rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/) now supports rails 4 as per https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/250

Answer (score 0):

The adapter now supports v4.2 as well.
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter