# How to generate SQL Server database from schema.rb file?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I have an MS SQL Server 2012 instance with managment studio and I have schema.rb file which contains the following:

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database.
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your database schema.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120525100324) do

  create_table "academic_details", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "registration_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "additional_exam_groups", ["school_id"], :name => "index_additional_exam_groups_on_school_id", :limit => {"school_id"=>nil}

  create_table "additional_exam_scores", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.integer  "additional_exam_id"
    t.decimal  "marks",              :precision => 7, :scale => 2
    t.integer  "grading_level_id"
    t.string   "remarks"
    t.boolean  "is_failed"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "school_id"
  end.................etc.
```

How to generate SQL Server database from that file?

Answer (score 1):

First, is your [Rails app properly configured to use MS SQL Server 2012 as its DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467772/ms-sql-server-with-rails-4)?

If so, try running `rake db:schema:load` task.

If that doesn't work, try running the `rake db:setup` task.

You can find more detailed information about the `rake` tasks here in this previous Stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302357/631834

Comment: Thanks @theSshow, I was browsing an open source project
https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena
I want just to discover the database design/schema, what is the best way to do that? I'm using ms sql server 2012 and never encountered mysql or ruby before.

Comment: Do you just want to set up a standalone database with the schema definition from the fedena project, or do you want to set up a Rails app? If setting up a Rails app, and you want to use a MS SQL Server, you'll have to probably use the [activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter).